# Ray из 2D коллайдера

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда нечего было делать, нашел функцию `Raycast` у класса `Collider2D` в `unity`. Мне стало интересно, откуда будет пускаться луч (я подумал, что из всех точек коллайдера). Решил протестировать, написал код и в результате столкновение ничего не выводит. Почему так? И откуда пускаются лучи?
Вот код скрипта теста:

```
    private Collider2D collider2d;

    private void Start() {
        collider2d = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        RaycastHit2D[] hits = null;
        collider2d.Raycast(Vector2.left, hits);
        Debug.Log(hits == null ? "No collusion" : hits.ToString());
    }
```

А вот сам скрин теста:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так же вывод сделать так:

```
RaycastHit2D[] hits = null;
Debug.Log(collider2d.Raycast(Vector2.left, hits));
```

В результате тож самое, только выводит "0"

Comment: "Casts a ray into the scene starting at the collider position". Наверно нет больше коллайдеров на сцене или не попадаются на пути.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код покажет вам первые три встреченных коллайдера

```
private void Update()
{
    // массив под три попадания
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[3];
    collider2d.Raycast(Vector2.left, hits);

    print("~~~~~~ начало попаданий ~~~~~~~~");
    foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
    {
        print(hit.collider);
    }
    print("~~~~~~ конец попаданий ~~~~~~~~");

}
```

Дело в том, что в отличии от 3д версии, у которой параметр RaycastHit идет с ключевым словом out, у 2д версии хиты - это массив, плюс без out массив уже должен быть инициирован. Задав вместо null массив из трех элементов, получаем первые три попадания в данном направлении.